# Multiple queries wordpress with same variable

Tags: wordpress

I have some question.

I have 2 queries.

query A:

```
$meta_queryA = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'course_id',
        'value'   => $post_slug_id,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
);
```

query B:

```
$meta_queryB = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'class_end_date',
        'value'   => $today,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
```

this queries placed in same function. Query B is related to Query A. Query B will show based on the comparison query A. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do a meta query with both of yours.

```
$meta_query = array(
     array(
        'key'     => 'course_id',
        'value'   => $post_slug_id,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'class_end_date',
        'value'   => $today,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
)
```